# Fragment Bundle receiving null value

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragment which i want to pass data from one fragment to another,the bundle has value from first fragment when sending but not receiving in another fragment.Here is the code:

First Fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_one,container,false);
    edemail = v.findViewById(R.id.ed_email);
    edpass = v.findViewById(R.id.ed_pass);
    btn = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            email = edemail.getText().toString().trim();
            password = edpass.getText().toString().trim();
            Customer_Frag2 cf2 = new Customer_Frag2();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Email",email);
            bundle.putString("Password",password);
            cf2.setArguments(bundle);
            Log.d("Test2",bundle.toString());
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Second Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
    ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_two,container,false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle!=null){
        email = bundle.getString("Email");
        pass = bundle.getString("Password");
    }
    Log.d("Test",email+pass);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Where is the transaction code ? How are you using Fragment `cf2` for Commit .?

Comment: @ADM I am also curious. This code doesn't seem to be doing anything with the `cf2` created other than setting arguments to it.

Comment: @Nivanraj Is the fragment even opening?

Comment: I have setup viewpager so that when the button clicked on fragment one,it will swipe to fragment two. Both fragment are opening too. Should i need to commit using viewpager element from mainactivity xml file?

Comment: use a listener with the host Activity. Let the activity send the value.