# Passing variable from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I currently having two fragments hosted in same activity. I want to pass string variable from fragment 1 to fragment 2. I try to use bundle but I'm getting null values only.

Fragment 1 Code :

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_one,container,false);
    edemail = v.findViewById(R.id.ed_email);
    btn = v.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            email = edemail.getText().toString().trim();
            Customer_Frag2 cf2 = new Customer_Frag2();
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("Email",email);
            cf2.setArguments(data);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.layout_one,cf2);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Fragment 2 Code :

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_two,container,false);
    tc = v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if(args != null){
        String myvalue = args.getString("Email");
        tc.setText(myvalue);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Other than using bundle,I also tried to use interface but couldn't get the string from fragment 1.

Comment: You have asked [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089456/fragment-bundle-receiving-null-value) yestreday.

Comment: I think you need to delegate the communication to your `Activity`, by implementing a listener

Answer (score 0):

In fragment2 do this:

```
    private String myvalue  = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         Bundle args = getArguments();
         if(args != null){
             myvalue = args.getString("Email");

         }
    }

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_two,container,false);
        tc = v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        tc.setText(myvalue);

        return v;
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: *Bundle is available it onCreate method not in onCreateView method*, that's not true. Is it?

Comment: @JeelVankhede I have read about it thanks for highlighting.

Comment: @NoumanCh still getting the same result...